# How to use SQLite working with EntityFramework 6 in Visaul Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to connect SQLite my WPF project Visual Studio 2012.

I have tried from below mentioned url, but not for me. The Server Explorer is not locating a connection to SQLite database from the Data Source.

https://erazerbrecht.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/sqlite-entityframework-6-tutorial/

http://erikej.blogspot.in/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html